# Sencha touch in webmatrix

Tags: sencha-touch, webmatrix, iis-express

I'm trying sencha touch in WebMatrix but not having much success.  Everything from the sencha library has been downloaded and IISExpress is running correctly but when I browse to index.html I get the following displayed in the browser?

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',

    controllers: ['Main'],
    views:  ['Main'],
    stores: ['MoreCards'],

    launch: function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xclass: 'Sencha.view.Main'
        });
    }
});
```

Any ideas what is going on?  WebMatrix isn't showing any errors and neither is Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out what the problem was in the end.  Basically IISExpress sees app.js and assumes you are working on a NodeJS project which adds handler info into web.config.  Either choose cancel to NodeJS set-up when creating a new project with an existing app.js file or remove the NodeJS config sections in the web.config file.